¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los elementos que están dentro de una grilla cuando se expandan empuje solo la columna y no la fila que tiene debajo?
Paso a explicarles lo que quiero lograr.
Tengo una grilla donde tengo cards dentro de ella. Las cards se pueden expandir al presionarlas y mostrar información. Como están todas acomodadas en 4 columas, quiero que al expandir cualquiera de ellas, en vez de mover toda la fila que está debajo de ella (Imagen 1), mueva solo la columna donde está ese elemento hacia abajo (Imagen 2).
La cantidad de las cards no son fijos, ya que el proyecto lo estoy desarrollando en React y las cards pueden ir agregándose o eliminándose.
No sé si hay alguna manera de lograr esto con grids. Espero sus respuestas. Gracias!.

Imágen 1

Imagen 2
CSS
.item-list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 320px);
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    row-gap: 1.2rem;

    .item {
        justify-self: center;
    }
}

JSX
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Item from './Item';

const ItemList = ({ serv, categSel }) => {
    console.log(serv.length)
    return (
        <div className='item-list'>
            {
                useEffect(() => {
                }, [categSel])

            }
            {
                serv.length > 0 &&
                    categSel.length > 0 ?
                    serv.filter(serv => serv.categoria == categSel).map((serv, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Item serv={serv} key={index} itemKey={index} />
                        )
                    }) :
                    serv.map((serv, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Item serv={serv} key={index} itemKey={index} categSel={categSel} />
                        )
                    })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ItemList


Ahí lo acabo de editar. Gracias!.

puedes dar una explicaccion de que has intentado hacer para solucionarlo???

Se puede hacer con grid-row con el valor span 2 para hacer que el elemento ocupe la celda justo por debajo, y un poco de JavaScript.
grid-row es un shorthand de las propiedades grid-row-start y grid-row-end.
Existe un truco en el que se puede usar una checkbox oculta para simular un evento 'click' y expandir el elemento sin JavaScript, pero el problema es que ese checkbox necesita referenciarse mediante un ID, y si tenés que agregar muchos de esos elementos expandibles seria inviable agregar un selector para cada uno de esos ID's... a no ser que uses SASS que te permite usar bucles for. Por eso opte por esta opción pero yo no descartaría el uso del checkbox.
Pero bueno que me voy de tema, aca esta el codigo:


[...document.getElementsByClassName('expandable-grid-item')]
  .forEach(item => 
    item.addEventListener('click', () => 
      item.classList.toggle('expanded')
    )
)
#container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.expandable-grid-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.expandable-grid-item:before {
  content: 'collapsed content';
  color: white;
}

.expanded {
  grid-row: span 2;
  height: 100%;
}

.expanded:before {
  content: 'expanded content';
  color: white;
}
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item expandable-grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item expandable-grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts2.js" defer></script>
</body>



Ten en cuenta que esto desplaza a los elementos que vienen después de la celda afectada por la expansion en +1 posición.
